# Using a model's sub-classes as choice options for that model raises NameError

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.8, django-1.9

We are trying to upgrade a legacy code's django version from 1.8 to 1.9. We have one model that is defined like this:

```
def _get_descendant_question_classes():
    stack = [Question]

    while stack:
        cls = stack.pop()
        stack.extend(cls.__subclasses__())
        yield cls

def _get_question_choices():
    question_classes = _get_descendant_question_classes()

    for cls in question_classes:
        yield (cls.slug, cls._meta.verbose_name)

class Question(models.Model):
    slug = "Question"
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=_get_question_choices(), default=slug)

class TextQuestion(Question):
    slug = "TextQuestion"

class SelectQuestion(Question):
    slug = "SelectQuestion"

...
```

Basically the model wants to use its sub-classes as choice options for one of its fields. It does this with traversing the model in a DFS manner and yielding all the sub-classes.

This code works in django 1.8 but in django 1.9 it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 324, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/saeed/saeed/survey/models.py", line 85, in <module>
    class Question(models.Model):
  File "/home/saeed/saeed/survey/models.py", line 99, in Question
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=_get_question_choices(), default=slug)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1072, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 161, in __init__
    choices = list(choices)
  File "/home/saeed/saeed/survey/models.py", line 65, in _get_question_choices
    for cls in question_classes:
  File "/home/saeed/saeed/survey/models.py", line 54, in _get_descendant_question_classes
    stack = [Question]
NameError: global name 'Question' is not defined
```

I understand the problem what I don't understand is how this works in django 1.8? What has changed in django 1.9 that causes this? What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: I'm getting an error about slug when I try to recreate this.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this; with Django 1.8, `python3 -m manage check` succeeds, while in Django 1.9 it raises a `NameError`.

There is nothing particular in [the Django 1.9 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.9/) that addresses this change in behaviour.

I would explain this Django 1.8 behaviour by noting that Django is notorious for doing “magic” on the code in order to allow referencing not-yet-executed parts of the code to define models. It is an anomaly from normal Python behaviour, and AFAICT an undocumented one.

So this would be a behaviour that was only accidental and undocumented (therefore should not be relied on), where in normal Python you would expect a `NameError` when referencing `Question` before it is defined.

Django 1.9 evidently made a change that reverts to the expected Python behaviour :-)

Answer (score 0):

The exception is due to, when the method `_get_descendant_question_classes` is defined, the class `Question` is not defined yet. So, you are referring something that doesn't exist.

You have a design issue here, note you have a cyclic dependency: `_get_descendant_question_classes` depend on `Question` and `Question` depend on `_get_descendant_question_classes`.

A quick fix could be to use [`get_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_models):

```
def _get_descendant_question_classes():
    stack = [get_model('yourappnamehere', 'Question')]
```

I'm not sure why you need that `type` field, but I'm confident that you can solve your original problem (what lead you to add that `type` field) in another simpler way.

Also, in case you need to know the "type" of a `Question` instance, you just need to check if the object has the attr `textquestion_ptr` or `selectquestion_ptr` or just use `isinstance`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, when the class variable `type`is initialized in the `Question` class, the `Question` class hasn't been created, and yet `_get_question_choices()`, which references the `Question` class, gets evaluated right away in order to assign a value to the `type`'s `choices`, resulting in a circular reference.

To avoid this issue, instead of evaluating `_get_question_choices()` right away during class declaration, you can initialize `type` with empty `choices` first, and then give it the preferred value in `Question`'s `__init__` method, which is called only after `Question` has been instantiated:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=(,), default=slug)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Question, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._meta.get_field('type').choices = _get_question_choices()
```